# If $m^{*}(E)<\infty$, then $E$ is measurable iff $m^{*}((a,b)\cap E)+m^{*}((a,b)\sim E)=b-a$ for all $a<b$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Question**

> Let E have finite outer measure. Show that E is measurable if and only
>   if for each open, bounded interval (a,b), b - a =$ m^*((a,b) \cap E) + m^*((a,b) $~ E)

I would like to prove "if" part. My proof is as follows

> Since E have finite outer measure, there exists an open set (a,b)
>   containing E. 
> Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then E $\subset$
>   $(a-\frac{1}{2k}, b+ \frac{1}{2k}) = I_k$. 
> By the assumption,
>   $\frac{1}{k}$ = $m^*$($I_k \cap E)  $ + $m^*$($I_k$ ~ E) =  m*(E) +
>   m*($I_k$ ~ E).
>   Thus m*($I_k$ ~ E) = $\frac{1}{k}$ - $m^*(E)$ <
>   $\frac{1}{k}$ < $\epsilon$ by Archemedian Property.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: You have your question in your title, not in your question. Moreover the question in your title is incomplete.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited it.

Comment: If $m$ is Lebesgue measure on the real line then already the first  sentence is wrong. For instance, a set $\Bbb Q$ of rationals has measure zero, but it is not contained in any bounded interval $(a,b)$.